# Problems with sending keystrokes in Blueprism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I'm wanting to sign into Mural automatically, but their web design requires a keystroke, but I can't get my design to work. I have tried, both global send keys and send events. Furthermore, the click center input doesn't seems to register. :/ Any suggestions? The delay is implemented as a recommendation by another user:

[image: Picture of general process]

Comment: You might benefit from reading through the [Blue Prism Development Best Practices guide](https://portal.blueprism.com/documents/development-best-practice). The use of static Wait stages, various floating/unconnected stages, and uneven and criscrossing links indicate this code will become more and more unmaintainable over time. Following the best practices linked above will help to alleviate future problems with the expansion and maintenance of this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by jnch, the problem is resolved by using global send keys and then using another navigation stage with click center. I believe this fixes the problem since the website demands borderline human interaction.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are trying to sign into [this page](https://app.mural.co/signin?ref=muralcoheader). I have succesfully written in its email textbox just recognizing the field with the application modeler (browser mode) and a Write stage.

As esqew suggested in the comments then when I tried to sign in there was an error saying "an email is required". The solution for me was to use Navigates, first with "Global Send Keys" action and then "Click Center" for the button.

If it is not that website and it's another one it might be helpful if you add a link to the website in your question.

There could be several reasons why your send keys or the click events are not working, in order to help you it would be necessary to see the configuration inside the stages in your object.

Comment: Unfortunately, as OP describes, this does not solve the issue. You'll still receive a message indicating you've left the field blank once you select the "SIGN IN" button. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/TIGYFJ8.png)

Comment: You are right, I hadn't gone that far. It doesn't seem to acknowledge the input by the write stage.
I tried with a Navigate stage though with "Global send keys" and it works fine for me, and then another Navigate with "Click Center" action on the button and it does work and tries to log in.

Comment: ^ As above mentioned this is how to fix the problem, and it's a general problem with many sites. Sorry for late clarification, but thanks for your response.